# Redux/React: You must pass a component to the function returned by connect. Instead received {}

Tags: react-redux

I'm new to react/redux. After created a project using create-react-app, I modified the index.js and App.js:

## index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';

function reducer() {
    return {
        message: 'hello, world'
    };
}

const store = createStore(reducer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
  <App />
  </Provider>, 
  document.getElementById('root')
)

registerServiceWorker();
```

## App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { connect } from "react-dedux";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>The message: {this.props.msg}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    msg: state.message
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

This is the simplest demo version I'm trying.
The error message is "You must pass a component to the function returned by connect. Instead received {}". I've been comparing my code with quite some tutorials but couldn't find the root cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe this, my code was

```
import { connect } from "react-dedux";
```

while the correct package name is react-redux. So after I change it to

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
```

It works! At least it proved I'm tying the code, not copy-pasting. This auto-complete feature tricked me.